# symfony 2.5.3 - bug in cache:clear --env=pro

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change Method in symfony, but when I want to clear cache, there is a problem:

root@Aspire:/var/www/html/mysym# php app/console cache:clear --env=prod 
Clearing the cache for the **prod** environment with debug **false**

I receiv FALSE in this case.

my routing.yml

```
webdevblog:
    resource: "@webdevblogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

my routing_dev.yml

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

my DefaultController.php

```
namespace webdev\blogBundle\Controller;

use [...]

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="index")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @Template()
     */

    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('webdevblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

Comment: `but when I want to clear cache, there is a problem.` and **WHAT** Problem? How should we help you when you don't tell us what the problem is?

Comment: I can not clear cash with this command:
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
I receiv FALSE in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you receive `false`? If you mean the message `Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false` it just says that it's clearing cache not for debug environment (but for `prod`, as you asked it).

But if you have any troubles clearing cache you can always just remove `app/cache` folder.